# Excel Conditional Formatting based on date in string

Tags: excel, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I am attempting to use conditional formatting on a column in a data set. I want to highlight any cell that is less than six months old. I can figure this out normally but it is someone elses data set I am attempting to modify without changing the data and the data in the column is stored as

> Last Sale: 07-18-2003 Sale Amount: $0.00

I can write formulas to pull the date out of the cell and I can write formulas to compare the date with today()-180 but when I attempt to do it as a conditional formula nothing happens. Anyone have a clue what I need to do to get the conditional formatting working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,12,10))>TODAY()-180`

Applies to: `$A:$A`

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: This didn't work for me but it may be my dd/mm/yyyy date settings.  I got it to work by pulling the Month, Year, Day seperately =DATE(MID(D13,18,4),MID(D13,12,2),MID(D13,15,2))>Today()-180 you could also use -EDATE(Today(),-6) to get Excel to calculate back 6 calendar months from the date.

Comment: This is what I was trying and was not having any luck but I figured out my problem. The data actually has a line break which seems to mess it up. The cells actual value is Last Sale: 12-26-2016 /line break
Sale Amount: $0.00. Any way to get around the line break breaking it up. I know the data being imported into this document is listed as Sale Date & char(10) & Sale amount.

Comment: The line break shouldn't affect anything, though I was adding 1 extra character. Try `=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,12,10))>TODAY()-180`

Comment: Are you using U.S. dates as Gordon was saying? May be best to get the day values separately. I would just make it easy on myself and strip out the random text and filter by dates.

Comment: Make sure that you are also setting your conditional formatting format to Fill a certain color. Check that your dates are actually within 6 months. Drag a formula down to the side and see what is being output by `MID(A1,12,10)`

Comment: The line break was the extra character being picked up. Changing it to 10 characters worked like a charm. Not sure what I was doing wrong earlier. Oh well, you are a life saver. Thanks a lot.